# Внедрение картинки в локальный HTML файл

Tags: html, dom

## Описание

Написал локальный сайт, точнее программу на обычном DOM. Поскольку программу нужно запустить на телефоне в офлайн режиме (а большинство телефонов не умеют прикрепить локальные файлы), я убрал из него все ссылки и собрал все воедино. К примеру:

```html
<script src="../js/script.js" defer>
```

поменял на...

```html
<script>
    /// весь код из script.js
</script>
```

Проблема в том что с картинками так не получается. Да и я не знаю способы внедрить ее в HTML файл. Ну и естественно по ссылке [она](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hEAG.jpg) не отображается.

## Вопрос

Что подскажите? Как внедрить картинку в HTML? Или есть ли другие способы решить данную проблему?

Comment: Тег `img` разве перестал работать?

Comment: @u_mulder она работает, но сайт на телефоне не просто открывается. Она клонируется где-то в подразделах проводника и открывается тот клон. А по ссылке из этого клона она ничего не находит, вот и не отображается.

Comment: Можете перекодировать картинку в формат base64 онлайн конвертером, это обычный текст, который можно вставить в `img` . [Вот пример](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html)

Comment: @MrFylypenko спасибо. Проблема решена. Оставьте решение как ответ и я приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перекодировать картинку в формат base64 онлайн конвертером, это обычный текст, который можно вставить в `img`. Пример кода:

```html
<div>
  <p>Красная точка ниже</p>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
        //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```